# Any Repeating text/phrase finder function/software for text editor? replace/remove?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, pdf, find-and-replace

I compile my own PDF for my personal use from texts copied from other sources and other ebooks I have purchased. When I copy texts from other PDFs, the chapter title, page # and book titile appear multiple times (same as # of pages) in the big single document I have pasted.

Is there any software which will find repeating phrases sentences in a big area of text so that I can replace/remove them?

The function/app should list all repeating phrases in the selected text area and offer suggestion to replace/remove.

Comment: This could be complicated, for example what is considered a phrase.  Would "the next step is..." be considered a repeated phrase?  or would "the next" be considered repeated.  I think you may need to do some scripting if what you are replacing has anything repeatable in it.

Comment: that's true. its complicated. but we set rules like minimum 4 words for a phrase to qualify

Answer (score 0):

Check [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com). It can be useful to compile a single ebook from multiple sources, also it may have header/footer removal functionality built-in. It's to use for with ebook readers but can be good enough for PC use as well.